# Como conectar codeigniter 4 con sql server

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

He buscado por todo lado como conectar CodeIgniter 4 con sql , pero las respuestas que encuentro hasta el momento es como conectar el Codeigniter 3 con sql , y  no he logrador realizar la conexion con mi sql

Comment: Mira Cómo preguntar para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el recorrido para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Comment: Codeigniter 4 no tiene todos los drivers convertidos, hasta donde yo se no se puede usar aun Microsoft SQL Server. Te dejo un link donde lo tratan y los drivers que ya tienen [Server Requirements Codeigniter](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/intro/requirements.html?highlight=mssql)